# How to work with serialized variables in a Javascript Script-Task in Camunda

Tags: javascript, java, camunda, script-task

Consider having a process variable like this:

```
Object type name: java.util.ArrayList
Serialization Data Format: application/x-java-serialized-object
Value: [{"id": 1, "name": "John"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Jane"]
```

I'm trying to write a Javascript within a Script-Task which extracts a variable, like above, and works with it. Here's how far I've come:

```
var arr = execution.getVariableTyped("arr", true);

for (var i=0; arr.size(); i++) {
    var item = arr.get(i);
    //Do somthing with `item`
}
//Add an object to the end of the array
arr.add({ "id": 3, "name": "Jack" });

execution.setVariable("arr", arr);
```

But when I run this, it throws the following error:

> Cannot complete task xxx: Unable to evaluate script: TypeError:
>   ObjectValue [value=[{"id": 1, "name": "John"}, {"id": 2, "name":
>   "Jane"]], isDeserialized=true,
>   serializationDataFormat=application/x-java-serialized-object,
>   objectTypeName=java.util.ArrayList, serializedValue=X chars] has no
>   such function "size" in <eval>

It's in the case that [ArrayList's reference](http://ect.bell-labs.com/who/yjchang/api/d9/db3/classjava_1_1util_1_1ArrayList.html) says that it's got `size` and `add` both!. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Camunda API you are calling:
[VariableScope#getVariableTyped](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.3/org/camunda/bpm/engine/delegate/VariableScope.html#getVariableLocalTyped%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) (DelegateExecution implements VariableScope). This method returns an instance of [TypedValue](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.3/org/camunda/bpm/engine/variable/value/TypedValue.html).

Use `execution.getVariableTyped("arr", true).getValue();` or `execution.getVariable("arr");` to access the actual ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks. Do you also know how can I address `Variables` class in Javascript? I tried `org.camunda.bpm.engine.variable.Variables` but it says class not found!? I would like to call `org.camunda.bpm.engine.variable.Variables.objectValue(v)` but I can't!